# SSRS 2008 Report Dynamic Header works on local machine in BIDS but not from Report Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services

I have a report that consists of a single column tablix with a single row that is grouped. Inside the row are three sub reports. The Header of the report is supposed to display three pieces of information unique to the data that the row is grouped on so the header is unique for each.

I attempted to populate the data in the header by having hidden controls in the body that I then referenced in the expressions of the controls in the header. This method didn't work. So I switched to a different possible solution I found which was to populate variables using VB and reference them in the header using `=Code.variableName` in the expression. The function to populate the variables is called from a hidden control in the body which passes the data as parameters.

This method worked. However, it only seems to work on my local machine and one of my coworker's machines in BIDS preview. When the report is published to the report server, it runs and everything seems fine, except the header values don't populate.

One of the variables is an integer and the other two are strings. The integer value is initialized to 0 and in the report from the report server it shows the initialized value of 0, but the strings are still blank. This makes me think that the function isn't being called or there might be a scope issue? Or it could be something completely different that I'm not familiar with. Possibly a configuration issue with the report server?

Here is the report:
[image: Screenshot of the report designer]

If you can see the tiny little control about halfway down the report on the left side. Its just a tiny little box.. The expression for that control is:

`=Code.GetHeaderData(Fields!SEPID.Value, Fields!FullName.Value, Fields!Level.Value)`

The Function is:

```
    Shared Public Dim SEPIDVar as Integer
    Shared Public Dim FullNameVar as String
    Shared Public Dim LevelVar as String

Public Shared Function GetStudentHeaderData(
    ByVal sepid as Integer, 
    ByVal fullname as String, 
    ByVal level as String)
        SEPIDVar = sepid
        FullNameVar = fullname
        LevelVar = level
End Function
```

The three header controls have the following expressions:

```
=Code.FullNameVar
=Code.SEPIDVar
=Code.LevelVar
```

And then here are some screenshots showing the difference in how the report looks when I preview it locally from BIDS vs running it on sql report server:

The working header when viewing preview in BIDS 2008 on local machine:
(values distorted) 
[image]

And the broken header when viewing the report from the report server:
[image]

I've spent multiple days now scourging the internet for a solution to no avail. Any help in troubleshooting why this is happening would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Report Server doesn't run your code before the header is created. Obviously, it seems to work in BIDS.

Can you move the headers down to be part of your report so you can just use the fields?

If not, have you tried using **ReportItems**? See this [TechNeT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255285(v=sql.110).aspx) for more info.

Comment: Trying it now @Hannover Fist